# Refresh token exception in identity server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Based on the below  i am working on refresh [Refresh token renewal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175302/handling-expired-refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core)

[image]
But after  token expired ,while request new refresh token am getting below error

[image]

Below is my code

```
   var tokenClientOptions = new TokenClientOptions
                        {
                            Address = "https://localhost:5000", //configuration.TokenEndpoint,
                            ClientId = "webclient",//openIdConnectOptions.ClientId,
                            ClientSecret ="secret"  // openIdConnectOptions.ClientSecret
                        };

                        var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
                        using var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

                        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(httpClient, tokenClientOptions);
                        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken, cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

below is my  Html response.

[image]

I have given base path idetity server 4.  Pls let me know reason am getting error..Thanks in advance.

Comment: The exception contains a HTML page in the `Raw` property, this page may contain more information about the error.

Comment: @MartinStaufcik i have updated  question.. Html respose added

Comment: Try `https://localhost:5000/connect/token` for `Address `

Comment: Thanks a lot its working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Token Endpoint of Identity Server](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html) to programmatically request tokens is `/connect/token`.

The URL of the address need to be `https://localhost:5000/connect/token`.

Comment: Thaanks ..How to redirct tl login if token expired?  below   if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                        {
                            context.RejectPrincipal();
                            return;
                        }

Comment: Refresh tokens allow requesting new access tokens without user interaction. You may need to set AllowOfflineAccess of the client to true, as described in the docs:  https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html.

Comment: Actually I have given AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime÷10 mins and  sliding 5 mins..within 10 mins I will refresh  token,.if I access after 10 mins it will not refresh the token right? Pls correct me if I wrong? In this case I need to redireht to login page...is it possible?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct. For redirect, it works with authorize request, as described 
 here: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html, so you would need to use `authorize` request instead of `token` in this case.