# Acess token refresh with OIDC in .NET Core 3.1, OnValidatePrincipal is never called/thrown

Tags: c#, .net-core, keycloak, openid-connect

I am making a POC of a small website that uses Keycloak as an OIDC provider, for now I am just using the "standard" scaffolded website that .NET Core generates. The `Privacy page` has an `authorize attribute` so that it can only be accessed if the user is authenticated.

My `StartUp.cs` looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
          services.AddControllersWithViews();
          services.AddAuthentication(options =>
          {
              options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
              options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
          })
            .AddCookie(i => new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnValidatePrincipal = context =>
                    {
                        return OnValidatePrincipal(context);
                    }
                }
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/WatchList/";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ClientId = "ClientID";
                options.ClientSecret = "20ea1950-af47-4251-85e9-7c4f33189c77";
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "groups",
                    ValidateIssuer = true
                };
            });

          services.AddAuthorization();
      }

      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
      {
          if (env.IsDevelopment())
          {
              app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
          }
          else
          {
              app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
              app.UseHsts();
          }

          app.UseHttpsRedirection();
          app.UseStaticFiles();

          app.UseRouting();

          app.UseAuthentication();
          app.UseAuthorization();

          app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
          {
              endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                  name: "default",
                  pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
          });
      }

      private async Task OnValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
      {
          const string accessTokenName = "access_token";
          const string refreshTokenName = "refresh_token";
          const string expirationTokenName = "expires_at";

          if (context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
          {
              var exp = context.Properties.GetTokenValue(expirationTokenName);
              if (exp != null)
              {
                  var expires = DateTime.Parse(exp, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime();
                  if (expires < DateTime.UtcNow)
                  {
                      // If we don't have the refresh token, then check if this client has set the
                      // "AllowOfflineAccess" property set in Identity Server and if we have requested
                      // the "OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess" scope when requesting an access token.
                      var refreshToken = context.Properties.GetTokenValue(refreshTokenName);
                      if (refreshToken == null)
                      {
                          context.RejectPrincipal();
                          return;
                      }

                      var cancellationToken = context.HttpContext.RequestAborted;

                      // Obtain the OpenIdConnect options that have been registered with the
                      // "AddOpenIdConnect" call. Make sure we get the same scheme that has
                      // been passed to the "AddOpenIdConnect" call.
                      //
                      // TODO: Cache the token client options
                      // The OpenId Connect configuration will not change, unless there has
                      // been a change to the client's settings. In that case, it is a good
                      // idea not to refresh and make sure the user does re-authenticate.
                      var serviceProvider = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;
                      var openIdConnectOptions = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<OpenIdConnectOptions>>().Get("Cookies");
                      var configuration = openIdConnectOptions.Configuration ?? await openIdConnectOptions.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                      // Set the proper token client options
                      var tokenClientOptions = new TokenClientOptions
                      {
                          Address = configuration.TokenEndpoint,
                          ClientId = openIdConnectOptions.ClientId,
                          ClientSecret = openIdConnectOptions.ClientSecret
                      };

                      var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
                      using var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

                      var tokenClient = new TokenClient(httpClient, tokenClientOptions);
                      var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken, cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                      if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                      {
                          context.RejectPrincipal();
                          return;
                      }

                      // Update the tokens
                      var expirationValue = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                      context.Properties.StoreTokens(new[]
                      {
                          new AuthenticationToken { Name = refreshTokenName, Value = tokenResponse.RefreshToken },
                          new AuthenticationToken { Name = accessTokenName, Value = tokenResponse.AccessToken },
                          new AuthenticationToken { Name = expirationTokenName, Value = expirationValue }
                      });

                      // Update the cookie with the new tokens
                      context.ShouldRenew = true;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

This all works as I expect it would: i can access the `Home page` without having to authenticate but if I want access to the Privacy page I am redirected to the Keycloak login page and after successfully logging in I have access to the `Privacy Page` as well.

However I want to access the `Acces Token` and `Refresh Token` (because I want to use the access token to access an api) as well, this in itself isn't a problem either:

```
  [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {

            var accessToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;
            Debug.WriteLine(accessToken);
            var refreshToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token").Result;
            Debug.WriteLine(refreshToken);
            return View();
        }
```

The problem is that these might be expired and I want to retrieve a new access token, but this should happen automatically.
I've tried the solution that was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61396951/9784279), and like you can see in my `StartUp.cs`, I "catch" the `OnValidatePrincipalEvent` and execute the code below.

But here is **the problem**: for some reason this event is never called. I would expect it to be called everytime I access the `Privacy page`. However this isn't the case, the event seems not be thrown ever.

Things I've tried:

- I've followed this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61396951/9784279, that seems to do exactly what I want, except for the fact that the event isn't thrown.
- Checked if other events work like expected: I have confirmed that `OnTokenValidated` and `OnTokenResponseReceived` are called like expected, however these are `OpenIdConnectEvents` and not `CookieAuthenticationEvents`.
- Tried playing with the `StartUp.cs` file, mainly the order/place of `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()`. But this didn't change anything.
- I thought maybe I could create an extension method `GetOrUpdateTokenAsync` on `HttpContext` that retrieves the `access token` and if it is expired it will retrieve a new one. The problem is that I don't think I have access to `StoreTokens` in
  `CookieValidatePrincipalContext`
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61396951/9784279

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am having the same problem.